# drop primary key if exists

Tags: mysql, constraints

I need a query that could drop primary key only if it exists.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

This will return error if it does not exists, but my requirement is to run a query in different databases.

Comment: Try to look into `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to see if the primary key exists first, then drop the primary key if exists? Can't be done in single query.

Answer (score 7):

In MariaDB 10.2.16 i was able to solve this problem with:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `PRIMARY`;
```

This should work with any table since the primary keys in MySQL are always called `PRIMARY` as stated in MySQL doc:

> The name of a PRIMARY KEY is always PRIMARY, which thus cannot be
>   used as the name for any other kind of index.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.',TABLE_NAME, 
' DROP PRIMARY KEY; ANALYZE TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.',TABLE_NAME, ';') 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME) IN  
    (SELECT CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
    WHERE INDEX_NAME = 'PRIMARY' -- *Required* to get only the primary keys from the statistics table.
    -- *Optional*
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'clients_database');
```

- Run this to generate your required SQL.
- Copy your results, then run them as working queries.
- ANALYZE TABLE is optional as well as the `WHERE` clause.
- You can remove `ANALYZE TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.',TABLE_NAME, ';'` if desired from the query below.

I exploit the information_schema when researching and utilizing standardization techniques.

`Just about` everything you would ever need or want to know about your tables and columns lives in some System table in either (if applicable)

Database / Table_schema:

- [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html)
- [performance_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema.html)
- [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/system-database.html)

> [Note: From doc's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-navigator.html)
>
> > Internal schemas, such as "performance_schema", "information"schema", "sys", and "mysql", are **hidden by default**. Toggle the Show Metadata and Internal Schemas preference to list them in the object browser. Schemas beginning with a "." are also controlled by this setting.

NOTE: [Here's something similar that has been created.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498072/information-schema-and-primary-keys)

Hope this helps!

Cheers,

Jay

Answer (score -1):

I think the easy option might be this:

first go to :
'YourDatabase'>tables>your table name>keys>copy the constraints like 'PK__TableName__0001'

then run this:

`Query:alter Table 'TableName' drop constraint PK__TableName__0001`