# How to retrieve all user tables, corresponding columns and data types in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

How do we retrieve all user tables, corresponding columns and data types, in a tabular format. This result can be used to supplement a data dictionary.

Eg Result set.

```
TableName - ColumnName -   DataType -      Nullable - Key etc
Department  DepartmentId   int             NO 
Department  Name           varchar(50)     NO 
Department  Phone          int             YES
Order       OrderId        int             NO
Order       OrderDate      datetime2       NO
```

PS: I am aware of

```
exec sp_columns 'TABLE_NAME'
```

but could not get to list all tables everything at once. (For further export to spreadsheet)

Comment: Have you had a look at the `sys` or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects?

Comment: You may check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498072/information-schema-and-primary-keys/6498182#6498182

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME , DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: Thank you. This just did the job.