# Database normalization: Foreign Key = Primary Key?

Tags: sql

I have a Table "Position" wich allready exists

- PositionID (PK) int
- PositionText
- ...

Now I have to create a new Table "PositionComment" (I'm not allowed to edit the Table Position, so I have to create a new one).
The relation is 1:0..1 (it is garantied through code, that 1 position can only have 1 comment).

So i need to have a primary key in this new table - but:

For the rules of normalisation:

Do I have to make the foreign key = primary key, because it is 1:0..1 
e.g.:

- PositionID (PK, FK to Position-Table)
- CommentText

OR

Do I have to make a own primary key
e.g.:

- CommentID (PK)
- PositionID (FK to Position-Table)
- CommentText

The difference is, ofc, that in the first suggestion I use a different PK as PK in the second table... But in the second suggestion I have a double Identifier because the CommentID and the PositionID will be unique for 1 row...

How to do this for the rule of normalization and why?

Comment: As far as DBAs are concerned, "guaranteed through code" is _exactly_ equivalent to "not guaranteed at all" :-) However, if you make it the primary key of the new table, it _is_ guaranteed. Through the DB. Where it _should_ be.

Comment: I would go with second option. What if relationship changes in future to accommodate for one to many scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are absolutely right, to implement a 1-1 relationship you should usually consider merging them into the same table. If you have a good reason not to do that, a good method to enforce the 1-1 relationship is to use the foreign key as a primary or alternate key in the referring table.

Answer (score 0):

[Please take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982992/is-it-fine-to-have-foreign-key-as-primary-key/).

It seems that someone else has asked a similar question before.

> Foreign keys are almost always "Allow Duplicates," which would make them unsuitable as a Primary Key.
>
> Instead, find a field that uniquely identifies each record in the table, or add a new field (either an auto-incrementing integer or a GUID) to act as the primary key.
>
> The only exception to this are tables with a one-to-one relationship, where the foreign key and primary key of the linked table are one and the same.

But you should also consider this:

> A composite primary key that consists of two foreign keys is also perfectly fine for implementing many-to-many relationships.