# Data Vault 2 can we build the satellites without having primary key defined?

Tags: database-design, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-vault

I am working on building a simple data vault model to upload it into snowflake. I am having a some sort of problem in all satellites. I know that adding auto incement surrogate keys into a sat is neither wrong nor practical, which means we can add it, but it will not represent anything to the whole design. Each SAT contains a hash key coming from the related HUB and represented as FK.

1. I think selecting `LOAD_DATE` as PK will result in duplicated PK values.
2. [And it is not logical to add a FK as PK in the same table where there is a one-to-many relationship between the HUB and its SATs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982992/is-it-fine-to-have-foreign-key-as-primary-key#:%7E:text=Primary%20keys%20always%20need%20to,one%2Dto%2Dmany%20relationship.)

Can we skip the part of adding a primary key to a SAT in DV2.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure where you are getting your DV modeling information but, adding an auto incremented surrogate key to a Sat is not in keeping with the DV standards at all. Never was.

PK of a Sat is ALWAYS the PK from the Hub (the Hub Hash key) plus LOAD_DTS. Hub to Sat relationship is ALWAYS modeled as 1:M.

So no - you cannot and should not skip having a PK definition for your Sat.

If you do not believe me - please read any of my blogs on data vault or the published data vault books from Amazon. You might also look at DataVaultAlliance.com

Comment: I believe you sir. but for the DDLs, should I set the LOAD_DATE as primary key within the DDL scripts?

Comment: And keep the hash as the FK coming from the hub ? I mean as in the DDLs

Comment: You need a compound PK with the Hash Key + LOAD_DATE plus keep the FK on the Hash Key to the Hub. See the diagram in the Hash Key section of this post https://www.snowflake.com/blog/tips-for-optimizing-the-data-vault-architecture-on-snowflake/