# Supported way to get Primary Key Name in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT @PrimaryKeyName = cu.COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE cu 
    WHERE EXISTS 
    ( SELECT tc.* FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc 
    WHERE tc.TABLE_NAME = @Item AND 
    tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND 
    tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME )
```

Which I'm using to get the Primary Key column name from a particular table.

The problem I have is that I see INFORMATION_SCHEMA is not supported in Azure SQL Database, even though the query does actually work.

Does anyone know a way of doing this in a supported way?

Comment: What do you mean not supported? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql the article is for SQL Databases Azure included

Comment: It has a X next to whether its supported by Azure SQL Database

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/1349385/2975396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the [main System Information Schema Views topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql) in the documentation does not indicate the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views are supported in Azure SQL Database, all of the view-specific doc pages do indicate the view is supported with sole the exception of [`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/key-column-usage-transact-sql). That seems a bit odd so it might just be a documentation issue. I'll reach out to see if I can confirm this.

I'd be inclined to use the SQL Server catalog views instead of ISO `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views unless cross-DBMS compatibility is specifically required since those include additional meta-data one may find useful.

**EDIT**

I confirmed with the product team that this is only a documentation issue. Both the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views and SQL catalog views are supported methods to query catalog meta-data in Azure SQL Database.